# Vampire spawn death vs vampire death

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

If a pc reduces a Vampire Spawn to 0hp, does it become gaseous like a vampire? If so, does that gaseous form function the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Vampire spawn](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#vampire-spawn) assume gaseous form at 0 hp like a [vampire](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#vampire) does

The [**vampire spawn**](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#vampire-spawn) (*Monster Manual* 253–4) possesses the extraordinary ability fast healing that, in part, says

> If reduced to 0 hit points in combat, it automatically assumes gaseous form and attempts to escape. It must reach its coffin home within 2 hours or be utterly destroyed. (It can travel up to nine miles in 2 hours.) Once at rest in its coffin, it is helpless. It regains 1 hit point after 1 hour, then is no longer helpless and resumes healing at the rate of 2 hit points per round. (254)

Thus, despite its fast healing functioning at a slower rate than a full-on vampire's (2 for the vampire spawn *versus* 5 for the vampire), the effects of either being reduced to 0 hp remain largely identical, and that includes a vampire spawn assuming gaseous form.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that... *Note to self: read the full text, even if you think you have it memorized*

Comment: @wolf Honestly, having recently *rewritten the vampire entry in its entirety* for personal use so that I could confirm all its nuances for my campaign, it's a *really* easy thing to miss, not being done any favors by being crammed in with the special ability fast healing. (Further, keep in mind that if you're running vampires that, in addition to not having reflections, they don't cast shadows!)

Comment: Yeah. Now i have to shoehorn about 15 coffins into a kings vault thats been sealed about a thousand years... Lol

Comment: @wolf My vampires have a tendency toward walling up access to their coffins, leaving only cracks so that they can get to their coffins and (most) others can't. In other words, put 'em behind walls or in the ceiling or whatever. No reason to leave a coffin sitting out in the open when a vampire can also assume gaseous form whenever it likes!

Comment: I like that idea... And it leaves the spawn for the next generation to deal with!

Comment: The shocking true story behind Mario Bros and all those pipes... read all about it in the next issue of the GT&L magazine. ;D